Difficulties finding the schematic for the coherent circuit
I am looking for a schematic called (I found it by name) a ''coherent'' and ''non-coherent'' circuit where the LNA is applied. I was able to find the "non-coherent" circuit, but even after googling and looking in books, I could not find the "coherent" circuit.
I would like to find the diagram of this "coherent" circuit, providing the name of a book or website.

Image from research paper:
A. Gerosa, M. Soldan, A. Bevilacqua and A. Neviani, "A 0.18-μm CMOS Squarer Circuit for a Non-Coherent UWB Receiver," 2007 IEEE International Symposium on Circuits and Systems (ISCAS), New Orleans, LA, USA, 2007, pp. 421-424, doi: 10.1109/ISCAS.2007.378553 (Also on Semantic Scholar)

A google image search suggests the figure is from the IEEE paper A 0.18-μm CMOS Squarer Circuit for a Non-Coherent UWB Receiver, published in 2007 IEEE International Symposium on Circuits and Systems (ISCAS). Found the link to the IEEE paper from https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-0.18-%CE%BCm-CMOS-Squarer-Circuit-for-a-Non-Coherent-Gerosa-Soldan/fe70c3813b6f8c0c27c0df878acb49a5594d9ec2. I don't have IEEE access to check if has detail about the coherent version.

@ChesterGillon  So, I took this image of the non-coherent one I found, so much so that it was the image I posted, I'm trying to find the schematic of the coherent one that I can't find

What is a coherent circuit?

It's hard to tell from the meager context here, or if it's a translation error (not so much really an error, but a difference in terminology; maybe the word choice is too literal, etc.), but there is some context that may be worth going into explanation of.
An incoherent detector is one which receives amplitude, magnitude, or envelope, of a signal, rather than the full (phase-accurate frequency domain, or instantaneous time domain) signal.  Put another way, phase information is destroyed in the process.  An AM detector is a classical case, and a squaring function is the go-to theoretical representation of it.  A photodiode, for example, is often called a "square law detector".
The article title, "a squarer circuit", suggests this is the aim of the circuit given.  MOSFETs are well known to have square-law or exponential response, so can be used in such a way; I'm not familiar with the details of the exact circuit shown, but it may be worth researching prototypical designs like the Gilbert Cell (which uses BJT exponentials to construct a product function; actually a dependent tanh function, but with further corrections, the circuit can be (bi)linearized over a wide input range; related functions, including square, and even sin/cos, can also be constructed; see related patents assigned to Tektronix in the 1960s).  Depending on bias voltage, M5 and M6 might be operated in triode mode, giving some useful characteristic, and the mismatch -- in channel width, I'm guessing -- of M1-M4 is important.  Evidently, important relative to bias current, suggesting a matter of how they are biased (probably in the quadratic (above-threshold) region).
In contrast to a diode, or other peak detector circuits, it may be that the authors wanted to create something suitable for wide bandwidth, with a broader usable square-law operating region, operating at low voltages and currents (hence the moderately-fine-pitch IC process).  Whereas a diode alone might not have as good response (e.g. bandwidth varies with bias), or have a narrower usable range (the exponential diode curve takes over at large signal levels), is sensitive to temperature, etc.
In contrast, a coherent detector is one which preserves phase.  To record phase, we require some kind of absolute phase reference.  This is usually supplied from a separate unit in the receiver, the local oscillator (LO).  The LO can be synchronized to others (say for synchronized antenna arrays, which today include up to global scope thanks to precise clocks and accurate synchronization methods), or run independently; "coherence" is a matter of opinion, as an LO might be "coherent" (synchronized, over some span of time and/or space) to another signal, or not (e.g. without synchronization effort, independent clocks eventually diverge, no matter how accurate; even the universe itself (general relativity) guarantees this under specific circumstances).
Typically, we receive RF signals by downconverting a segment of bandwidth, so that it can be processed more easily (IF), or converted into a signal having direct meaning (baseband).  This might be radio frequencies as low as MHz (well, really, even 10s of Hz, in ELF), or extend up to 100s of THz (optical frequencies).  When this is done with a mixer (a multiplication between the RF signal and the LO signal), the output remains coherent (again, as coherent as the LO and signal themselves are, anyway).
The analogous coherent circuit, then, would seem to be a mixer.  Perhaps LO is included as well, but there is no standalone equivalent: the phase reference (LO) must come from somewhere.
